# What is the name of this Czech bread?

Tags: bread

I recently went to a Czech restaurant and ordered the meal pictured below. It was well made and is one of my favorite meals at that restaurant. I want to try and make the "bread" (if that's what it's called) that was on the dish, but I can't figure out what it is. Here's a photo of it:
[image]

My best guess is that it's some kind of potato bread.

Comment: It might help if you would include the name of dish you ordered and, perhaps, the restaurant.

Comment: Did it taste baked? I have a vague memory that Czech cuisine has a kind of Serviettenknödel, that would be old bread shaped into lumps, packed in cheesecloth, and steamed or cooked. The picture looks more like that than like baked bread. Another possibility is a pancake-like item.

Comment: @rumtscho may have hit on it; google image Serviettenknödel (and +1 for that recall).

Comment: @rumtscho I think it was baked, and your description sounds right- I'll look it up to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell for 100% certain from that photo, but I believe it may be Houskove Knedliky, a sort of unstuffed dumpling common to many Czech dishes. The variety in your image looks similar to Houskove Knedliky v Ubrousku, literally "Bread Dumplings [cooked] in a Napkin":

http://www.trixicooks.com/2015/10/houskove-knedliky-v-ubrousku.html

You can find several recipes for that variety of houskove knedliky, though when I lived in the Czech Republic ordinary houskove knedliky (i.e. not the "in napkin" style) were far more common as sides to dishes like Svickova, Gulas, etc.:

http://recepty.vareni.cz/kynute-houskove-knedliky/

If you want to find recipes for ones made from potatoes, add the word "bramborove" to your searches. Here's one example I found:

http://www.mimibazar.cz/recept/94046/bramborove-knedliky-v-ubrousku

Comment: Are there also some which are both in a napkin and with potatoes?

Comment: This one appears to be: http://www.mimibazar.cz/recept/94046/bramborove-knedliky-v-ubrousku

Unfortunately I'm not too much of an expert on Czech cuisine despite living there for two years